# Cleaning Pandas column on specific data type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I'm trying to clean some columns and there are a few things I've encountered.
There is a bunch of sales data with binary values for each product.

Attached is a sample of the dataset.

The process has been to `dropna` first. Then, there are column values such as   and `11` which don't match the desired binary value. I've tried a few things here such as

```
#### THIS SHOULD BE CLOSE 
def clean_empty_string(df, col):
    df = df[df[col] != 1] or df[df[col] != 0]
    return df

for i in df.columns:
    clean_empty_string(df, i)

# this does the same except not in a function
#cleandata4bestdeal = cleandata4bestdeal[cleandata4bestdeal['DellLaptop'] != ' ']

def get_index_names(df, col, val):
    index_names = df[df[col] == val].index
    return index_names

def drop_index_names(df, idx):
    df.drop(idx, inplace=True)
    return df


idx = get_index_names(df, 'DellLaptop', ' ')

drop_index_names(df, idx)
```

When I try:
`df = df[df['DellLaptop'] != ' ']`
This works, but when I insert it into the `clean_empty_string` function, I get

`ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Can someone give me some direction on what could be wrong here?

Heres how a column looks:

'Product': [0,1,Nan,11, ' ']

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the binary values, this should do the trick:

```py
df = df[df[col].isin([0, 1])]
```

Comment: That's the correct answer-thanks!